# extracting a username from an email (Python)

Tags: python, list, email

I'm working on a side project for work where we're trying to automate an email that goes out. There's basically three lines of the email that change and the rest is just a form email. The section that changes is just sending the name of the user, their username, and their email address.
For example:
Credentials:

First Last

flast

first.last@email.com

Before putting everything together, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to automate putting the full name, username, and email in without prompting the users for it. I'm trying to use the email to get the name and username into this section. I've got the full name figured out, but the best that I can do for the username is getting the first initial and the last name with a space in between.

Here's my code:

```
email = "first.last@email.com"
elist = email.split('@')[0].replace('.', ' ')
name = elist.title()
print(name)
unamelist = elist.split(" ")
print(unamelist[0][0], ''.join(unamelist[1]))
```

I know my issue is that I'm returning two separate indexes in the list, but I'm not sure if there's a way to take out the white-space that gets printed. Right now the output would be `f last`

Comment: what should be the right answer?

Comment: There shouldn't be a space. Ideally it would be 'flast'

Answer (score 0):

```
print(unamelist[0][0], ''.join(unamelist[1]))
```

Whenever you have multiple arguments separated by commas, `print()` will insert a space between them.  That's where the space is coming from.

Instead of using a comma, use a plus sign to join the two strings together:

```
print(unamelist[0][0] + ''.join(unamelist[1]))
```

Comment: Well I feel kind of dumb for not realizing that. For some reason I thought I was returning lists and couldn't do that. Thanks!